# Debugging After a solution is published - c# VS2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

So I have a solution that works fine on my dev PC, but then when I publish it (one-click) im hitting an error that simply doesn't exist in debug mode. I'm working on it, however it bought me to a question that I don't know the answer to: After publishing, are there extra debugging tools you can use that aren't hard coded? For example, you can always print to a console and such, but I want more, such as saving a stack that follows certain variables to a file if an exception is thrown.

Anybody know of anything like this or Is it a pipe dream?

Comment: You may be looking for application tracing, where you add trace calls to your methods to output diagnostic data. There are tools that can add this without code like Postsharp, or you can do it manually. There are also events in the app domain that allow you to catch unhandled exceptions and log information before the application terminates.

Comment: Cole - AFTER publishing i.e once its no longer running through VS.

And Ron - Ill look into that, thanks :)

Comment: Even when deploying you want to deploy both exe and pdb file as well as handle all unhandled exceptions, etc.  Release code compared to debug is optimized and it's actually another configuration (which has own settings, maybe you forgot to set one properly in release), so it still has to have proper error handling.